# How to express $\sqrt{21}$ in a linear combination of powers of $\sqrt{6}$ and $\sqrt{14}$ over the rationals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory

Algebraically, we know that $\sqrt{21}$ can be expressed as a linear combination of$\sqrt{6}$ and $\sqrt{14}$ over the rationals because $\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{14}) = \sqrt{5+\sqrt{21}} $ and $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{6},\sqrt{14}] = \mathbb Q[\sqrt{5+\sqrt{21}}]$ and because $\sqrt{21} \in \mathbb Q[\sqrt{5+\sqrt{21}}]$ obviously we have that $\sqrt{21} \in \mathbb Q[\sqrt{6},\sqrt{14}]$ so $\sqrt{21}$ must be a linear combination of the powers of $\sqrt{6}$ and $\sqrt{14}$. I'm not sure how to go about showing this, though.

Comment: It needn't be a linear combination but it must be in the form $a + b\sqrt{6} + c\sqrt{14} + d\sqrt{6}\sqrt{14}$ which ... is easy to show as $\sqrt{6}\sqrt{14}= 2\sqrt{21}$.

Comment: To complement Hagen's answer, no such linear combination exists.

Comment: Also to complement Hagen's answer $\sqrt{21}\in Q[\sqrt{6},\sqrt{21}]$ does *not* mean $\sqrt{21}$ is a linear combination but merely in the field.  So $\sqrt{21} = a + b\sqrt{14}$ where $a,b\in Q[\sqrt{6}]$ so $\sqrt{21}= (c +d\sqrt{6}) + (e + f\sqrt{6})\sqrt{14}$ where $c,d,e,f$ are rational which is easy to solve.

Comment: Are you talking about this?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_dependence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a *linear* combination, but
$$\sqrt{21}=\frac12\sqrt 6\sqrt{14}. $$

Answer (score 7):

If $\sqrt{21}=a\sqrt{6}+b\sqrt{14}$ with $a,\,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $21=6a+14b+4ab\sqrt{21}$. For both sides to be rational requires $ab=0$. If $a=0$ then $b^2=\frac{3}{2}$, contradicting the rationality of $b$. Similarly, if $b=0$ then $a^2=\frac{7}{2}$, contradicting the rationality of $a$.